# How to get all field information of class received as Generic?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How to get all field information of class received as Generic?

I gave Account.class as the constructor of GenericClass, and executed the `t1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();` command to get the field information of the class.

But as a result, the size of declaredFields was 0.

The debug result shows the following result.

```
result = {Field[21]@10835}
 0 = {Field@10837} "private static final int java.lang.Class.ANNOTATION"
 1 = {Field@10838} "private static final int java.lang.Class.ENUM"
 2 = {Field@10839} "private static final int java.lang.Class.SYNTHETIC"
 3 = {Field@10840} "private transient volatile java.lang.reflect.Constructor java.lang.Class.cachedConstructor"
 4 = {Field@10841} "private transient java.lang.String java.lang.Class.name"
 5 = {Field@10842} "private transient java.lang.Module java.lang.Class.module"
 6 = {Field@10843} "private transient java.lang.String java.lang.Class.packageName"
 7 = {Field@10844} "private final java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.componentType"
 8 = {Field@10845} "private static java.security.ProtectionDomain java.lang.Class.allPermDomain"
 9 = {Field@10846} "private transient volatile java.lang.ref.SoftReference java.lang.Class.reflectionData"
 10 = {Field@10847} "private transient volatile int java.lang.Class.classRedefinedCount"
 11 = {Field@10848} "private transient volatile sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository java.lang.Class.genericInfo"
 12 = {Field@10849} "private static final java.lang.Class[] java.lang.Class.EMPTY_CLASS_ARRAY"
 13 = {Field@10850} "private static final long java.lang.Class.serialVersionUID"
 14 = {Field@10851} "private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] java.lang.Class.serialPersistentFields"
 15 = {Field@10852} "private static jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory java.lang.Class.reflectionFactory"
 16 = {Field@10853} "private transient volatile java.lang.Object[] java.lang.Class.enumConstants"
 17 = {Field@10854} "private transient volatile java.util.Map java.lang.Class.enumConstantDirectory"
 18 = {Field@10855} "private transient volatile java.lang.Class$AnnotationData java.lang.Class.annotationData"
 19 = {Field@10856} "private transient volatile sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType java.lang.Class.annotationType"
 20 = {Field@10857} "transient java.lang.ClassValue$ClassValueMap java.lang.Class.classValueMap"
```

Account information is as follows.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    // User ID
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userid;

    // username
    private String username;

    // user password
    private String password;

    // User Permissions
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountRole role;
```

The test code is as follows.

```
@SpringBootTest
class PlxEntityToExcelTest {
    
    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @Test
    void basic() {
        System.out.println("accountRepository = " + accountRepository);
        Iterable<Account> all = accountRepository.findAll();
        for (Account account: all) {
            System.out.println("account = " + account);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void anyClass() {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setUserid("test");
        account.setUsername("username");
        account.setPassword("qwer");
        account.setRole(AccountRole.USER);
        accountService.createAccount(account);

        Iterable<Account> all = accountRepository.findAll();

        GenericClass<Account> cn = new GenericClass<Account>(Account.class);
        cn.entityToExcel((List<Account>) all);




    }

    public class GenericClass<T>{
        private T t1;



        public GenericClass(Class<T> specificClass) {
            this.t1 = (T) specificClass;
        }

        private void createHeader(){

            Field[] declaredFields = t1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();


        }
        public void entityToExcel(List<T> list) {
            System.out.println("list = " + list);
            createHeader();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense and wouldn't ever function. For example, you accept a `Class<T>` specificClass, and then assign it to a field of type `T`. Which will never work - the concept 'the string class' is not at all the same as `"Hello, World!"`.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly what you are trying to do, you are trying to get the fields of the class Account. In that case you do not need to cast the clazz instance to an Account instance in the constructor of GenericClass and therefore you only need to do `t1.getDeclaredFields();`

Here is the code with the right changes for GenericClass

```
public class GenericClass<T>{
    private Class<T> t1;



    public GenericClass(Class<T> specificClass) {
        this.t1 = specificClass;
    }

    private void createHeader(){
        Field[] declaredFields = t1.getDeclaredFields();


    }
    public void entityToExcel(List<T> list) {
        System.out.println("list = " + list);
        createHeader();
    }
}
```